# Validation input to be string only and numbers only JAVA

Tags: java

I am a student and i have a little problem with validation inputs.

```
String name;
System.out.println("Enter name:");
name = keyboard.nextLine();
//If name contain other than alphabetical character print an error

double number;
System.out.println("Enter number:");
name = keyboard.nextDouble();
//If number contain other than number print an error
```

What i have tried is test to parse the string to double but i could not.
I have no idea how to test if the double is only number.

Please give me a clue of what i should do.

Comment: use regex `[A-Za-z]` for name and `\\d` for numbers. but dont you think name can contains other than alphabetical character, *whitespace* for example?

Comment: @christopher Not a duplicate, since this asks about validating both numeric and non-numeric inputs. But clearly heavily related.

Comment: Incidentally, a down-vote from me. This topic has been discussed numerous times on this site and you should have been able to find an answer with some prior research.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)  to check if the input match your constraint as follow :

```
String name;
System.out.println("Enter name:");
name = keyboard.nextLine();
if (!name.matches("[a-zA-Z_]+")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid name");
}
String number;
System.out.println("Enter number:");
number = keyboard.nextLine();
if (!number.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number");
}
```

[Here is](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) a good tutorial to learn regex .

Comment: Almost right - but you must read the number as a string if you want regex to work. Plus, you should really indent your example code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each character of the `String` and check if it's not alphabetic using `Character.isAlphabetic(char)`:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter name:");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();

for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isAlphabetic(c)){
        System.out.println("INVALID");
        break;
    }
}
```

To only accept numbers, you can do something similar using the `Character.isDigit(char)` function, but note that you will have to read the input as a `String` not a `double`, or get the input as a `double` and the converting it to `String` using `Double.toString(d)`.

Comment: char c = evt.getKeyChar();

        if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) || contactMobile.getText().length() == 10) {

            evt.consume();

        }

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = 0;
try {
    number = Double.parseDouble(name)
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Name is not a double.");
}
```

If `number` is not a double, you can catch a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `scanner`. If you are, you can use the `Scanner` class' `hasNextDouble()` to check if the input is a double before reading the double as shown below:

```
double number;
System.out.println("Enter number:");
if (keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
    name = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

Have a look at the `Scanner` class [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the "fancier" regex solution.
[Java Pattern Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

You can use this (untested code) given you used nextLine() for reading BOTH inputs:

```
 boolean isWordOnly = Pattern.matches("\w*", name);    //name is in your code
 boolean isFloatOnly = Pattern.matches("\d*.?\d*", number);    //number is in your code too
```

Now the too boolean values tell you if there is the desired format in your input. You can add it in a do - while loop or anything you want.

It is a good idea to start studying reg(ular) ex(presions) because they are useful in string formatting (Imagine that you have to test if the input is a valid email...). Also used to check for SQL injections and many key things in apps and programs generally.